# How to read csv from S3 bucket using spark.read.csv function?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I want to read the data from S3 bucket and the result will show like this picture bellow. I want to ensure that the compiler has a header in the raw data and can estimate the data types for all columns. So what are suitable arguments for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtW0L.png)

The code is df = (spark.read.csv("s3a://raw-recipes-clean-upgrad/RAW_recipes_cleaned.csv", argument to show the header, argument to estimate the data types))

I'm stuck with this. Any recommendation for me? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding `header` and `inferSchema` `options` as shown below.

Then spark will infer the `datatypes` and `treat first line as header`.

For all the available options for spark csv reader refer [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html)

```
spark.read.option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).csv("s3a://raw-recipes-clean-upgrad/RAW_recipes_cleaned.csv")
```